# Getting Android camera preview

Tags: android, android-camera

Im trying to make a very simple camera app, and Im running into a brick wall here as the camera preview isnt showing up. Ive followed the Developer guide: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Here is my code:

```
package com.zygotelabs.gallileo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private Camera mCamera;
    private Preview mPreview;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        //task.execute();
        if (safeCameraOpen()){
             Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Camera object is valid, starting preview");
             mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
        }
    }


     private boolean safeCameraOpen() {
            boolean qOpened = false;

            try {

                releaseCameraAndPreview();
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                qOpened = (mCamera != null);
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "Camera has been opened");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return qOpened;    
        }

        private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

}
```

And the PreviewClass

```
public class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);
        //mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewCameraPreview);
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
        requestLayout();
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);

        // Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface.
        // Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

        stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

        mCamera = camera;

        if (mCamera != null) {
            List<Size> localSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = localSizes;
            requestLayout();

            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("CameraPreview", "Error setting up the preview display");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview
            // surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
            Log.e("CameraPreview", "Camera preview starting");
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }


    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    /**
     * When this function returns, mCamera will be null.
     */
    private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
            // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
            // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
            mCamera.release();

            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, Im a bit confused regarding the SurfaceHolder. Currently Ive just created a very simple layout that I use in the activity that contains a surfaceView. But the code I currently have seemingly adds a new SurfaceView, but where is it supposed to show up? If I try to assign my already existing surfaceView, I get a nullpointer exception, but with the code Im currently using I get "app passed NULL surface". So Im guessing there is something wrong with the surfaceView stuff here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11689388/192373), this `Preview extends ViewGroup` pattern is used. But note: they set `Preview` as the main (content) view of the `Activity`:

```
onCreate() {
   ...
   setContentView(mPreview);
}
```

You can do the same, or `addContentView(mPreview)`. True, in this case you don't need to define a `SurfaceView` in your layout XML.

Alternatively, you can use the `SurfaceView` that is part of your layout. But in this case `Preview` class should not *extend* `ViewGroup`, but only *implement* `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.

In this case, you still have `mSurfaceView;` member, and the constructor is as follows:

```
Preview(Activity parentActivity) {

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewCameraPreview);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}
```

Here `surfaceViewCameraPreview` should be a child of `main_layout`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if the Preview class does not extend ViewGroup, I seemingly cant do super(context) and cant call requestLayout(), etc.

Comment: What do you mean _does not extend_? This is not a question of what you can do. "extends ViewGroup" is in your code. Have you changed it since posting?

Comment: Yeah but you described a viable solution where I should not be extending ViewGroup, but by doing that I get some other issues elsewhere I'm not quite sure how to go about resolving.

Comment: True, `super()` is not needed anymore, my fault. Fixed. What other issues do you find? And well, I suggest an alternative that keeps inheritance from `ViewGroup`. But you cannot associate **mSurfaceView** with an item in layout XML; you can only insert it into the layout dynamically.